# How does multilevel model make predictions for levels not in test data?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, prediction, multilevel-analysis

Multilevel models are able to make predictions for levels that are not in the test data, but I'm unsure why or how this is possible. Here's an example to illustrate where I use a test data set with data from only 20 U.S. states, but then get predictions from the model for all 50 states:

```
# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Data
dat <- tibble(
  y = rnorm(1000, 0, 1),
  state = rep(sample(state.name, 20), 50)
)

# Model
model <- lmer(y ~ (1 | state), data = dat)

# Prediction data
new_data <- data.frame(state = state.name)

# Get predictions
predict(model, newdata = new_data, allow.new.levels = TRUE)
```

How is this possible? How were predictions generated for the 30 U.S. states that weren't in the test data? I'd be happy if anyone could explain or point me to a resource that can explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model will make predictions based on the estimated fixed effects only (just the intercept in this case)

This is justified because the the random effects are assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean zero, therefore the expected value for any new lavel (state) is 0.

Note that your code produces the following output for the predictions:

```
> head(predict(model, newdata = new_data, allow.new.levels = TRUE))
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
0.02534702 0.01612787 0.01612787 0.01612787 0.01612787 0.01612787
```

And we have the estimated fixed intercept as:

```
> getME(model,"beta")
[1] 0.01612787
```

There are other ways to do it. For example, we could sample from a normal distribution with mean zero and the same variance as estimated by the model.